# Recover SAPUI5 project from HCP

Tags: sapui5, hana, sap-cloud-platform

So my PC crashed and my HDD's file structure was corrupted to the point of no recovery. The application is still deployed on HCP and I was wondering if it is possible to fetch the deployed project files from the HCP server?

Comment: By *is still deployed on HCP* you mean that you have been developing a HTML5 application? If so then just connect from another computer and clone the repository.

Comment: I would, the app never got uploaded to git

Comment: Just open the WebIDE from HCP Cockpit, in the WebIDE navigate to </>, right click on your package and select "Export". This will download a .zip with all your files.

Comment: Awesome I didnt know about that. When I try to access the WebIDE I get a blank screen?

Comment: Yes, that happens sometimes. Just reload (hold shift key to clear cache) or close the tab and try again.

Comment: Okay so whats happening is that it prompts me to log in to success factors, once logged in the screen is blank. I'm guessing I need to contact SAP support for this

Comment: @Nic, care to make that an answer?

Answer (score 0):

To download the source files of an existing UI5 project from the HANA Cloud Platform do the following:

- login to HCP Cockpit
- from the Cockpit navigate to "HTML5 Applications"
- open the WebIDE by clicking the "edit" button next to your
  applications name
- in the WebIDE navigate to "" on the menu bar
- locacte your package from the package tree
- right click on your package node and select "Export"

This will download a .zip with all your source files.

Comment: Thanks alot Nic, will the source files be there even if i have never used the WebIDE before?

Comment: How did you deploy them? With HANA Studio? If they have been deployed to HCP the will be there.

Comment: I deployed it using eclipse? Its a java application though and not an HTML5 application

Comment: It says SAP UI5 and nothing about Java in your question. If it is a Java application deployed as a WAR you can not easily download it, nor, if you could download it, get your sources back, because usually the WAR contains only .class files, not the .java sources.

Comment: It's a java app with SAPUI5 frontend. Yes, I received confirmation from SAP that it is not possible to recover the .war file. Apparently they cannot recover anything from the HCP servers. I find this hard to believe